# Terminal display broken after killing python curses program

Tags: python, curses

I wrote a small program in python and outputted some screen display using the curses library.  For my simple output this seems to work.  I run my python program from the command line.

My problem is that if I kill the python program the terminal doesn't properly display.   For example:
  'ls -al' displays properly before I run my python curses program
  'ls -al' does not display properly after I kill the python curses program.

What can I do to make my terminal display output properly after I kill my python curses program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually the `reset` command will reset your terminal settings to default values.

Answer (score 5):

If you use curses.wrapper, it will handle all the cleanup (and set up) for you. http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.wrapper

Answer (score 4):

Initialize the curses the following way, it will handle a cleanup.

```
class curses_screen:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.stdscr = curses.initscr()
        curses.cbreak()
        curses.noecho()
        self.stdscr.keypad(1)
        SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_WIDTH = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()
        return self.stdscr
    def __exit__(self,a,b,c):
        curses.nocbreak()
        self.stdscr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()

with curses_screen() as stdscr:
"""
Execution code plush getch code here
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Register a [signal handler](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html) that will uninitialize curses.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `curses.endwin()`. It restores the terminal window...
In fact if you don't call it after program is closed terminal will show everything like it is in the curses window...